# Error - Visualisation data in ggplot2 with ggrepel package

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, ggrepel

I tried to draw a graph in the ggplot2 library with the addition of ggrepel:

```
set.seed(42)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(wt, mpg), size = 5, color = 'grey') +
  geom_label_repel(aes(wt, mpg, fill = factor(cyl), label = rownames(mtcars)),
                   fontface = 'bold', color = 'white',
                   box.padding = 0.35, point.padding = 0.5, 
                   segment.color = 'grey50') + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

But I got the following error:

> ```
> Error in convertUnit(x, unitTo, "x", "dimension", "x", "dimension", valueOnly = valueOnly) : 
>   'x' argument must be a unit object
> ```

Thanks?

Comment: i ran your code only adding `library(ggplot2)` and `library(ggrepel)` and it ran without error.

Comment: Thank you. I do not know why my fault is? I use version R 3.4.0

Comment: Same here, using ggrepel_0.7.0 and ggplot2_2.2.1

Comment: I could reproduce the error message in a clean session, on R 3.4.1 & ggrepel_0.6.5. Try changing `box.padding = 0.35, point.padding =  0.5` to `box.padding = unit(0.35, "lines"), point.padding =  unit(0.5, "lines")`?

Comment: Thanks a lot  Z.Lin !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is caused by:

```
box.padding = 0.35, point.padding = 0.5
```

[ggrepel version 0.6.11](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/blob/master/NEWS.md#ggrepel-0611-2017-07-08) was changed to accept numbers such as `0.35` or the returned value from `unit(0.35, "lines")`.

If you're using ggrepel before version 0.6.11, then please try using:

```
unit(0.35, "lines"), unit(0.5, "lines")
```

My guess is that you're probably using ggrepel 0.6.5 from CRAN. You might consider updating to the latest version from CRAN, which is 0.7.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamil. I did it !